# Ubuntu booting to grub after 22.04.1 LTS upgrade to 22.10

Tags: boot, grub2, upgrade

Today I updated from `Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS` to `Ubuntu 22.10` using `sudo update-manager -d` (updated up to date).

Now when I try to boot from the drive I get this message:

```
GNU GRUB  version 2.02
Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible
command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.
grub>
```

Any help to restore the boot process properly?

Comment: I had a similar problem with 22.10 after selecting `Try Ubuntu` from a USB stick. The only way I could find to recover from this was to restart the PC and select to enter the BIOS setup to change the boot order - which did the trick.

Comment: @24601 thanks a lot it worked by reordering the boot order in the UEFI without actually changing anything to the ubuntu itself.

Comment: If you don't mind accepting that as an answer, I'll post as such since that may help others with the same problem.

Comment: @24601 how do I accept that as an answer?

Comment: click on the grey tick to the side of the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a similar problem with 22.10 following selecting `Try Ubuntu` from a USB stick, the only way I could find to recover from this was to restart the PC and select to enter the BIOS setup to change the boot order.

This resolved the issue.

Comment: very vague answer, how to select BIOS setup ? how to change boot order ? in what order the boot will take place ? nothing is mentioned

Comment: I think most people know how to enter the BIOS on boot and it's different for different machines. Often pressing `Esc` works as the machine is at POST stage but there are other methods. An individual would either know or check accordingly. To try to answer every type would be beyond the scope of the question The answer provided answered the OP and was accepted by the OP as such.